# Why am I still blocked to ask questions?

Tags: support

On the Biology SE-site, I was (and still am) blocked to ask questions:

[image]

I have done editing, as required, but the block still has a grip on me.
WHY?

Comment: check if you have deleted questions.

Comment: Looking at your profile over at Biology it looks like the edits you made did bring new attention to those posts but that didn't lead to a better reception, as a matter of fact you received a couple of downvotes. If your edits aren't seen as improvements then you only are doing the quality ban algorithm a favor.

Comment: Your recent questions have a distinct problem lack of quality and some of them are problematic for the SE network. I'd strongly urge you to take a week studying the scope of the site and their site-specific metas so you can improve the quality of the questions you've asked. See which ones are salvageable and which aren't.

Comment: Your questions here on Meta Stack Exchange haven't been so well-received either (net score -39 from four non-deleted questions). You could be in danger of being blocked from asking questions here too.

Comment: @RobertColumbia I'm shaking like a leaf! My rep. here is +359, though.

Comment: +352, actually.

Comment: @Ollie I was pretty sure is was +357, nut you're right indeed.

Comment: By the way this question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th received over 200 votes!

Comment: That main meta post you linked has all the answers to your question here. This is automatic, not by any mod, and there is nothing we can do. It happens when you post lots of poorly received questions. Your edits have to actually improve the posts and attract people to upvote them. Trivial or bad edits won't do this and will probably do worse.

Comment: @BryanKrause So I have to edit again? Who decides my edits has improved the questions? I know they have to conform to the guidelines.

Comment: Everyone else that visits the site and reads your questions decides.

Comment: It is probably also because you re-postet a deleted answer.

Comment: One of your edits was to add irrelevant information, which I rolled back and left a comment explaining why you shouldn't edit questions to include non-question content. *Your response was to then edit that exact same content back in*, so I removed it again and locked the question so you couldn't do it again right away. This does not seem like behavior from someone trying to improve the quality of their content on the site.

Comment: @BryanKrause What question was that?

Comment: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/80689/why-does-inbreed-produce-a-higher-percentage-of-abnormal-babies

Comment: @BryanKrause But that isn't a homework question, as is stated in the reason for the closure. Why is it thought that is a homework question? And is that the only reason to block me from asking further questions?

Comment: Like I said (and as mentioned in that main meta question you linked to, I hope you've read through all that), mods have no involvement in question bans like this. The question ban is due to a large number of poorly received questions, not any one single question. I explained in the comment why it was closed as homework, and explained that you should not add in the argument you added.

Comment: @BryanKrause Okay, that's been put clearly. I If I have a question I always can find it somewhere else.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder I've upvoted some of your excellent questions! I hope that your question ban will end soon.

Comment: @AYX.CLDR https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me